# How To Compare Int Var With Contents of A Struct

Tags: go

Using Go 1.11. Got the following struct,

```
type inputsData struct {
  TurnOne   int
  TurnTwo   int
  TurnThree int
  TurnFour  int
  TurnFive  int
  TurnSix   int
  TurnSeven int
  TurnEight int
  TurnNine  int
}
```

Which holds the data from user input. That is all fine but I want to check from `TurnTwo` if what the user inputs is already been entered?

Example, `Input 1 -> 6`, `Input 2 -> 4`, `Input 3 -> 6`

So what would happen is once the user inputs 6 for turn 3 again, it would log, sorry try again...

So this is how I am checking,

```
func checkInputTwo(userInput int) bool {
   var ok bool
   ok = true
   if userInput == t.TurnOne {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnTwo {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnThree {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnFour {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnFive {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnSix {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnSeven {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnEight {
    ok = false
   }
   if userInput == t.TurnNine {
    ok = false
   }

   return ok
}
```

This is how I am loading that function,

```
func checkStageTwo(input int) int {
  var ok bool

   fmt.Println(ok)

   for ok {
      ok = checkInputTwo(input)
      fmt.Println(ok)
   }

   fmt.Println(ok)

   return input
}
```

And I just load that function supplying it a input. This does not work. It allows the same input in, but once that match, I just get stuck within my for loop printing false?

So basically I want to check what the user input is and if its within the contents of my struct. I have load the struct package wide so its available for all the functions.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do, your method/variable names are confusing. It seems like you might want to store your input ints in a slice of ints. That would let you easily iterate over the slice to evaluate whether an incoming input is already present.

Comment: I was trying to use structs to get how they work. But I come from PHP and find it crazy that you cant loop over a struct? Unless I am wrong? Yes I have a var and want to see if any of the data within the struct matches that var. Basically want to loop over the struct and check the output with a var. But not sure that is possible?  Sorry for the confusion I am not very good at explaining myself.

Comment: I have a lot of PHP experience too. Think of structs as objects, slices as arrays. In PHP you'd never loop over an object...nor is there a need to loop over structs in Go. I am thinking you might want to rethink your data structure.

Comment: Yeah I see your point - I was sort of seeing them as supped up array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your specific use case is but based purely on the code shown, this should really be a slice or array instead of a struct. A struct with numbered fields is a very unusual design. A struct with numbered fields is a very unusual design and very difficult to work with, as you've found. If it were a slice, you could simply loop over it:

```
func checkInput(userInput int, pastInputs []int) bool {
    for _,i := range pastInputs {
        if userInput == i {
            return flase
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: ok, so change it to use a slice rather than a struct? I don't understand while you can not loop over a struct, seems a little limited?

Comment: You can't loop over a struct using `range` because a struct's fields can be different types. You could loop over it using reflection, but that would be extremely slow and overly complex. Your data structure is a numbered list of items which are all the same type; this is the exact use case for slices/arrays, so there is no reason to use a struct for this.

Comment: ok thanks, that makes it clear. I knew your could not range over a struct but could not see why. But yeah I get it if they are all different data types there would be no way of doing that. Many thanks.